# Deleting multiple rows in a HTML table using checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I can't delete the rows that are selected.
I want to delete the rows checked with checkbox. But I can't access the table rows and check whether the checkbox is checked. What should I do?

**Code:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-1">
    <table id="table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>edit</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="select"></td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="select"></td>
        <td>A3</td>
        <td>B3</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="select" class="select"></td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button onclick="deleteRow();">Remove</button>
  <script>
    function deleteRow() {
      var table = document.getElementById("table");
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      console.log("rowcount : " + rowCount);
      for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
        var c = table.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes;
        console.log(c);
        if (c.checked == 1) {
          console.log("i :" + i);
          table.deleteRow(i);
        }
      }
    }.
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `querySelectorAll()` and `:checked` to select all checked checkbox.

`parentNode.parentNode` is to get parent `tr` node

```js
function deleteRow() {
  document.querySelectorAll('#table .select:checked').forEach(e => {
    e.parentNode.parentNode.remove()
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-1">
    <table id="table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>edit</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="select"></td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="select"></td>
        <td>A3</td>
        <td>B3</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="select"></td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="deleteRow();">Remove</button>
```

**Note:** Avoid using duplicate `id`

Comment: Adding some info on why the approach of TO doesn't work would make this answer even better. Now TO has a working solution but doesn't know why his approach didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The way you go about deleting the rows is wrong, because you use a `for` loop with a pre-cached length, but when a row, say `i`, is deleted then the row `i+1` becomes `i` and the length changes.

A correct way to solve this problem is to use a `while` loop without caching the number of rows and incrementing the index only when you don't delete a row.

**Example:**

```js
function deleteRow () {
  /* Cache the table. */
  var table = document.getElementById("table"); 
  
  /* Create the index used in the loop. */
  var index = 1;
  
  /* Repeat as long as the index is less than the number of rows. */
  while (index < table.rows.length) {
    /* Get the input of the cell. */
    var input = table.rows[index].cells[0].children[0];
    
    /* Check whether the input exists and is checked. */
    if (input && input.checked) {
      /* Delete the row at the current index. */
      table.deleteRow(index);
    }
    else {
      /* Increment the index. */
      index++;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-1">
    <table id="table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>edit</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="select"></td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="select"></td>
        <td>A3</td>
        <td>B3</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="select" class="select"></td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button onclick="deleteRow();">Remove</button>
```

Comment: _"A correct way to solve..."_ - Yes, but it would be way easier to delete the rows from the end, because then the index will always be correct without additional "magic" (`for (let i = table.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }`) :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that after deleting a row, the index of all subsequent rows immediately decreases by one because `HTMLTableElement.prototype.rows` returns a ***live*** `HTMLCollection`.

That not only leads to your loop executing too often (because you cached `table.rows.length`), but also to subsequent indexes no longer matching.

I'd suggest using the much more readable `for...of` loop, which only gets slightly more complicated because tables don't seem to allow for using `table.removeChild(row)`:

```js
function deleteRow() {
  const table = document.getElementById("table");
  for (const [index, row] of [...table.rows].entries()) {
    if (row.querySelector('input:checked')) {
      table.deleteRow(index);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>edit</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="select"></td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="edit" class="edit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="select"></td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="edit" class="edit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="select"></td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="edit" class="edit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="deleteRow();">Remove</button>
```